# translate asp.net dynamic data web application into another language?

Tags: c#, asp.net

As the title told, I had a asp.net dynamic web application & want to translate labels (which are fields come from database)in asp.net dynamic data web pages to labels into another languages?

Suppose I have table called product has field called "Product Name=> without space" which will appears in dynamic web page as "Product Name" but i want to show that label into another language?
what is the best solution to do that dynamically?

[image]

Comment: So is that a detailsview? Please provide enough information we have no way of knowing how that page is generated, share the designer code.

Comment: labels are inside entity template control  <asp:EntityTemplate runat="server" ID="EntityTemplate1">
    <ItemTemplate>
         <tr class="td">
             <td class="DDLightHeader">
                 <asp:Label runat="server" OnInit="Label_Init" OnPreRender="Label_PreRender" />
             </td>
             <td>
                 <asp:DynamicControl runat="server" ID="DynamicControl" Mode="Insert" OnInit="DynamicControl_Init" />
             </td>
         </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:EntityTemplate>